# Postgres retrieve all rows if where condition is empty

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Am trying to get record from a database with several conditions that are dynamic

[image]

I want to switch where conditions with respect to what the user choices with a single query not multiple ones. Using python as development language

For example Year = 2019, Class = 'P1' Stream = 'all' gender - 'all' nationality = 'south african'

where ever 'all' is selected i wanted all the record to be returned. how can i achieve this with a single sql select query

Comment: Show us your current code attempt as well.

Comment: where (yearparam = ALL or yearparam = year) and ... etc

Comment: select * from pupil_detail_tb where year = '2019' and gender = coalesce('all', gender) # I want to be able to retrieve all rows if user picks 'all' as condition.

Comment: select * from pupil_detail_tb where pupil_no = coalesce('all', pupil_no);

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way to do this is to send all the fields to the query and do something like this:

```
select * from table where ($pupil_number='' or pupil_number= $pupil_number) 
and year= $year and class= $class 
and ($stream='All' or stream=$stream)
and ($state='All' or state=$state)
and ($gender='All' or gender=$gender)
and ($nationality='All' or nationality=$nationality)
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select * from tableName where Year = 2019 and Class = "P1" and nationality = "south african"
```

If all is getting selected ,then no need no apply where clause

Comment: That is not SQL.

Comment: please see the updated comment I missed to replace , with 'and' in where clause

Comment: 'all' is not in the database. though i want to return all the record where 'all' is the condition

Comment: so don't put those columns for which you want to fetch all records.So neglect those column in sql query.

Comment: the conditions are dynamic and ever changing. how can i achieve this without multiple if statements in sql

Comment: ok.Store UI result in dict(column name as key and value as value)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, where `$class` is what the user selects and you add dynamically. I.e. if the user selects `All` then you will basically evaluate `Class = Class` which will return all rows. And you can do the same for all conditions of course.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   CASE WHEN $class = 'All' THEN Class else $class END = Class
...
```

This is assuming both the user input and the column in your table can't be null.

EDIT: I should add that a better solution is probably to append the conditions programatically and starting with something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   1 = 1
```

That way you can append all your conditions starting with `AND` without having to worry about `WHERE`. This would make the sql cleaner and would perform better.